# Access loop index in the current elements data attribute - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I wanted to access the current index of a loop inside another attribute of the same element that has the `v-for` directive.

The HTML content is :

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="count in length" data-my-attribute="here" class="target">{{count}}</div>
</div>
```

And the JS code:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el : '#app',
    data: {
        length: 9,
    }
});
```

I know I can access the current loop index 'inside' the `div` with the class `target`. 
The way it does with the `{{ count }}`

But is it possible to access the `count` inside the value of the attribute `data-my-attribute` ?

(I mean in the place of the word "here")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could access that variable using the binding as follow :

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="count in length" :data-my-attribute="count" class="target">{{count}} </div>
</div>
```

like the case when you want to define a dynamic `id`s

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="count in length" :id="'divNum'+count" class="target">{{count}} </div>
</div>
```